# Azure ComputeManagementClient doesn't return response when list of snapshots is requested

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to get list of snapshots in azure subscription using below code. But ComputeManagementClient doesn't return response when list of snapshots is requested. The for loop is not iterate over list of snapshots.

```
    rg_list=resource_client.resource_groups.list()
    for item in rg_list:
        logging.info(item.name)
        snap_list=compute_client.snapshots.list_by_resource_group(item.name)
        logging.info(snap_list)
        for snap in snap_list:
            logging.info(snap.name)
```

OUTPUT:

```
RGA-ResGrp
[06/08/2020 03:16:05] <azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_11_01.models._paged_models.SnapshotPaged object at 0x7f7d538fa1d0>
```

Comment: Could you please check if you have created snapshots in the resource group : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/snapshot-copy-managed-disk?

Comment: [SnapshotPaged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-netapp/azure.mgmt.netapp.models.snapshotpaged?view=azure-python)  . Your snap_list is of type SnapshotPaged which can be iterated only if the resource group you provide has of type "Microsoft.Compute/snapshots" in it.

Comment: There are 34 managed disk incremental snapshots available in one of resource group. In above I have posted only one row output.

Comment: You might want to create a bug instead https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues

Comment: The issue got resolved after I added contributor role at subscription level to service principal. Earlier the role was Virtual Machine Contributor role only. But I am not getting why compute_client.snapshots.list_by_resource_group("<resource-group-name>") not returned any error like unauthorized to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not reproduce your issue, there are three incremental snapshots in my resource group, it works on my side.

[image]

Try the code works for me:

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    tenant='<tenant-id>',
    client_id='<client-id>',
    secret='<client-secret>')

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, "<subscription-id>")
snap_list=compute_client.snapshots.list_by_resource_group("<resource-group-name>")
print(snap_list)
for snap in snap_list:
    print(snap.name)
```

[image]

**Update:**

To iterate over list of snapshots, make sure the service principal have the enough permission e.g. `Contributor` role in the subscription.

Comment: The issue got resolved after I added contributor role at subscription level to service principal. Earlier the role was Virtual Machine Contributor role only. But I am not getting why compute_client.snapshots.list_by_resource_group("<resource-group-name>") not returned any error like unauthorized to access.

You can reproduce same issue by editing role assignment at subscription level. Only assign Virtual Machine Contributor Role to Service Principal and see result.